# Render partial for collection from a shared view directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my index action:

```
def index
  @cats = Cat.all
end
```

Here is the index view:

```
#views/cats/index.html.erb
<h1>Listing Cats</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Meows</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render partial: "shared/animal", collection: @cats %> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this partial, located in the `shared` folder, to display each cat:

```
# views/shared/_animal.html.erb
# I purposely did not name it views/shared/_cat.html.erb 
<tr>
  <td><%= cat.name %></td>
  <td><%= cat.age %> </td>
  <td><%= cat.meows %> </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> `undefined local variable or method 'cat' for #<#`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `animal` instead of `cat` – your partial is called `_animal.html.erb` and within it, you can refer to `animal` to get the instance that is being rendered.

```
<tr>
  <td><%= animal.name %></td>
  <td><%= animal.age %> </td>
  <td><%= animal.meows %> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What should be `animal` instead of `cat`?

Comment: Thanks suslov! You've helped me out a ton lately!

Answer (score 1):

The error you get `undefined local variable or method 'cat' for #<#` means that you don't have 'cat'

So you should use a variable accessible from your view, iterate over the @animals list is what you look to do I think so here is a solution.

You can rename @cats to @animals if you want to use the partial shared/animals

but you have also to iterate over the array you are retrieving in your controller

you can use the following code as solution :

Controller :

```
def index
   @animals = Cat.all  # or Dog.all ...
end
```

index view:

```
#views/cats/index.html.erb
<h1>Listing Cats</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Meows</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render partial: "shared/animals", collection: @animals %> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

animals partial view:

```
# views/shared/_animals.html.erb
# because I am using this as a basis for a bigger issue I'm trying to figure out
<% @animals.each do |animal|%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= animal.name %></td>
    <td><%= animal.age %> </td>
    <td><%= animal.meows %> </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: say in that index I have `@cats` AND `@dogs`.  How does the `@animals` know to grab the `@cats`, and is it possible to specify `@dogs` instead?

Comment: `@animals` can represent  a list of any animal, so you can use the shared view above to show it. but all animals models SHOULD have attributes we show in that view.